# Who are Ananta, Siddhesvara, Ekarudra and Srikantha?

Tags: identification-request, shaivism, deity

In [this chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-agni-purana/d/doc1083534.html) of Agni Purana, it mentioned the four deities, Ananta Ekarudra, Siddheshvara and Srikantha.

> After having worshipped duly the limbs, one has to worship the subtle Ananta. One should worship (Lords) Siddheśvara having a single eye, Ekarudra having three eyes, Śrīkaṇṭḥa wearing the peacock’s tail in the directions of east.

I wanted to know about them. So, my question is, Who are these deities? Is that Ananta actually Adisesha?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ślokas, quoted by the OP, are as follows-

> iṣṭāṅgāni yathānyāyamanantaṁ sūkṣmamarcayet / 
> siddheśvaraṁ tvekanetraṁ pūrvādau diśi pūjayet // 
> ekarudraṁ trinetrañca śrīkaṇṭhañca śikhaṇḍinam /
> eśānyādi vidikṣvete vidyeśāḥ kamalāsanāḥ // 
> ~ *Agni Purāṇa* ([304.27-28](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.325872/page/n599/mode/2up?view=theater))

Here, Ananta, Sūkṣma, Siddheśvara, Ekanetra, Ekarudra, Trinetra, Śrīkaṇṭha & Śikhaṇḍī, are mentioned. These eight are vidyeśvaras (as śloka#28 says too - *vidyeśāḥ*). Ananta doesn't refer to Ādiśeṣa (i.e. āsana of Nārāyaṇa) here. The translation, quoted by the OP, is slightly inaccurate, as it doesn't list Sūkṣma, etc., which are mentioned in the Sanskrit śloka. These vidyeśvaras (and their pūjā) are mentioned in several Śaivāgamas. Their names in Śaivāgamas are - Ananta, Sūkṣma, Śivottama, Ekanetra, Ekarudra, Trimūrti, Śrīkaṇṭha and Śikhaṇḍī. In Agni Purāṇa (304.27-28), Śivottama and Trimūrti are called Siddheśvara and Trinetra, respectively.

Mṛgendrāgama Vidyāpāda (4.2-5) describes the Vidyeśvaras -

> tatrādau kevalāṇunāṁ yogyānāṁ kuruteṣṭakam /  
> vāmādi śaktibhiryuktaṁ saptakoṭi paricchadam //  
> teṣāṁ anantassūkṣmaśca tathā caiva śivottamaḥ /  
> ekanetraikarudrau ca trimūrtiścāmitadyutiḥ //  
> śrīkaṇṭhaśca śikhaṇḍī ca rājarājeśvareśvarāḥ /  
> īrśadprāpta yogitvāt niyojyāḥ parameṣṭhinaḥ //  
> sarvajñatvādi yoge'pi niyojyatvaṁ malāṁśataḥ /  
> parasparaṁ viśiṣyante mantrāścaivaṁ adhassthitāḥ // 
> ~ *Mṛgendrāgama Vidyāpāda* ([4.2-5](https://www.himalayanacademy.com/view/mrgendra-agama-vidya-pada))

And Kāmikāgama pūrvabhāga mentions their rūpas, with the diśās, in which their pūjā is done -

> vidyeśvaro dvitīye anantādyā yathākramam / 
> ananteśaśca sūkṣmaśca śivottamaikanetrakau // 
> ekarudrastrimūrtiśca śrīkaṇṭhaśca śikhaṇḍikaḥ /  
> ete devāścaturvakkā haravaddaśabāhavaḥ //  
> khaṇḍendu maulayassaumyāṅ padmāsthā vividhāyudhāḥ / 
> khadgakheṭa dhanurbāṇa kamaṇḍalvakṣa sūtriṇaḥ // 
> varābhaya karopetāḥ śūlapaṅkaja pāṇayaḥ /  
> yugāntāditya saṅkāśāssaṁśṛṣṭau śivacoditāḥ //  
> anantaḥ pūrvataḥ pūjyaḥ sūkṣmaṁ dakṣiṇato yajet /  
> śivottamaṁ tu vāruṇyāṁ ekanetraṁ tathottare // 
> ekarudraṁ tathaiśānyāṁ trimūrti cāgnigocare / 
> śṛikaṇṭhaṁ caiva naiṛtyāṁ vāyāvyāṁ tu śikhaṇḍinam // 
> ~ *Kāmikāgama Pūrvabhāga* ([4.462-467](https://www.himalayanacademy.com/view/kamika-agama-purva-pada-part-1))

Comment: The links contain the translations, if anyone is interested in reading in English.

Comment: One small doubt: Is there any origins of these Vidyeshvaras?

Comment: @Boovanaes I have quoted Mṛgendrāgama Vidyāpāda (4.2-5) in the answer, and that mentions what you're asking about. The english translation is also linked in the answer, if you want that.